# How to run cron job only on single instance in AWS AutoScaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, autoscaling

I have scheduled 2 cronjobs for my application.

My Application server is in an autoscaling group and I kept a minimum of 2 instances because of High availability. Everything working is fine but cron job is running multiple times because of 2 instances in autoscaling.

I could not limit the instance size to 1 because already my application in the production environment I prefer to have HA.

How should I have to limit execute cron job on a single instance? or should i have to use other services like AWS Lamda or AWS ELasticBeanstalk

Comment: If the cron job has no dependency on the machine, better to have [CloudWatch Event Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) and invoke the lambda.

Comment: Maybe look at solution in gist referenced in answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/727466/running-crontab-on-aws-auto-scaling-group

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you should consider whether running the crons on these instances is suitable. If you're trying to keep this highly available and it is directly interacted via customers what will the impact of the crons performance be?

Perhaps consider using a separate autoscaling group or instance with a total of 1 instances to run these crons? You could launch the instance or update the autoscaling group just before the cron needs to run and then automate the shutdown after it has completed.

Otherwise you would need to consider using a locking mechanism for your script. By using this your script write a lock to confirm that it is in process, at the beginning of the script run it would check whether there was any script lock in progress. To further prevent the chance of a collision between multiple servers consider adding jitter (random seconds of sleep) to the start of your script.

Suitable technologies for writing a lock are below:

- [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) using [strongly consistent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) reads.
- [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) for a Linux application, or [FSX](https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/) for a Windows application.
- [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) using [strong consistency](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/).

Answer (score 2):

Solutions suggested by Chris Williams sound reasonable **if using lambda function is not an option**.
One way to simulate cron job is by using CloudWatch Events (now known as EventBridge) in conjunction with AWS Lambda.
First you need to write a Lambda function with the code that needs to be executed on a schedule. Lambda supports [cron expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html).
You can then use [Schedule Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) with EventBridge/CloudWatch Event in the same way as a cron tab and mention the Lambda function as target.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable termination protection on of the instance. Attach necessary role & permission for system manager. once the instance is available under managed instance under system manager you can create a schedule event in cloudwatch to run ssm documents. if you are running a bash script convert that to ssm document and set this doc as targate. or you can use shellscript document for running commands